# Compilation error when installing Realtek 8192cu driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek, scripts

I'm using a laptop with Ubuntu 13.04 64 bits. After "fighting" for some time, I gave up trying to have my Realtek 8188ce wireless card work properly (the wifi connection is annoyingly unstable).

So I decided to buy a wireless USB adapter (USB stick). It's a D-Link Wireless N 150 Micro USB Adapter DWA-121. To get it working, one needs to download and install the Realtek driver 8192cu from [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8192CU) (and load the 8192cu module).

I've done it successfully in the past, but I've also encountered the same problem as what follows. I think it worked after some upgrades, but right now I can't find a fix. I've upgraded `linux-headers-generic`, `linux-source` and `build-essential`, to no avail.

After downloading the driver, one must run the install.sh script to install it. My problem is I get the following compilation error:

```
root@brice-laptopLDLC:/home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105# ./install.sh 
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105.tar.gz
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/clean
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ieee80211.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ht.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_osintf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ioctl.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_event.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_rf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_rf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_sreset.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/recv_osdep.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_recv.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_cmd.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/generic.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/little_endian.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/swabb.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/swab.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/byteorder/big_endian.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/pci_osintf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_ops.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CPhyReg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_service.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/usb_osintf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_spec.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/pci_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CPhyCfg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_pwrctrl.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_cmd.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DETestHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_version.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ethernet.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_br_ext.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_qos.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_p2p.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_xmit.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/xmit_osdep.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mp_ioctl.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_xmit.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_spec.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/usb_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/pci_ops.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mp.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CEHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/mlme_osdep.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/h2clbk.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_ops_xp.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/usb_vendor_req.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_eeprom.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/farray.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DPhyCfg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ioctl_cfg80211.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_dm.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/if_ether.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types_ce.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_security.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ioctl_rtl.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DUHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CUHWImg_wowlan.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_led.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_led.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/wlan_bssdef.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mlme_ext.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DPhyReg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/wifi.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192d_recv.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_event.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DEHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192CUHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/nic_spec.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_intf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_ops_ce.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_ops_linux.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/circ_buf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_byteorder.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_xmit.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DUHWImg_wowlan.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ioctl_set.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_dm.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mlme.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/mp_custom_oid.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ip.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_ioctl_query.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/hal_init.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_conf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/Hal8192DUTestHWImg.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types_linux.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/autoconf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_ce_service.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_efuse.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_cmd.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sdio_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_io.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_led.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/ieee80211_ext.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/cmd_osdep.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/sta_info.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_iol.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/usb_ops.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_hal.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_debug.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types_xp.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtl8192c_rf.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_android.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/basic_types.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_mp_phy_regdef.h
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_rf.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_mlme.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_eeprom.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_io.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_br_ext.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/.tmp_rtw_wlan_util.o
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_iol.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_p2p.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_ioctl_set.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_debug.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_xmit.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_ieee80211.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_pwrctrl.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_security.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_ioctl_query.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_ioctl_rtl.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_sta_mgt.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_wlan_util.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_mp.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/.rtw_wlan_util.o.d
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/efuse/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_recv.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/Makefile
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/ifcfg-wlan0
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/wlan0dhcp
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/osdep_service.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/pci_intf.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/sdio_intf.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/Kconfig
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_sreset.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_dm.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_hal_init.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_cmd.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_phycfg.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_xmit.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_ce.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_led.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_halinit.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg_wowlan.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_xp.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_recv.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rxdesc.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_mp.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/hal/hal_init.c
rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm .tmp_versions -fr ; rm Module.symvers -fr
rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/rtl8192c/usb ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/rtl8192c ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-30-generic/build M=/home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105  modules
make[1]: entrant dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic »
  CC [M]  /home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_service.h:575:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  daemonize("%s", "RTKTHREAD");
  ^
In file included from /home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types.h:69:0,
                 from /home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.c:24:
/home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h: In function ‘rxmem_to_recvframe’:
/home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h:626:30: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  return (union recv_frame*)(((uint)rxmem>>RXFRAME_ALIGN) <<RXFRAME_ALIGN) ;
                              ^
/home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h:626:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  return (union recv_frame*)(((uint)rxmem>>RXFRAME_ALIGN) <<RXFRAME_ALIGN) ;
         ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/brice/Téléchargements/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105] Erreur 2
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic »
make: *** [modules] Erreur 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, I didn't search well enough, a [solution](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=13755671#p13755671) was linked to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307871/cannot-install-the-rtl8188c-driver-on-13-04?rq=1). I suppose a mod can delete this question.

Comment: I adivce you to update to ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: The solution you link to is in French, right? You would provide huge value to this platform by translating it, putting it into your answer, and marking your answer as solution.